# Why is extracting to a component not working?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently learning React and when I try to extract the Person List into its own component, an error appears. The error `String contains an invalid character` is not helping me, I tried debugging for a while now.

**App.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Person from "./components/Person";

const App = () => {
    const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
        { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '040-123456' },
        { name: 'Ada Lovelace', number: '39-44-5323523' },
        { name: 'Dan Abramov', number: '12-43-234345' },
        { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', number: '39-23-6423122' }
    ])
    const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Phonebook</h2>
            <form>
                <div>
                    name: <input/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">add</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <h2>Numbers</h2>
            {persons.map(person => {
                return (
                    // <p key={person.name}>{person.name} {person.number}</p> <--- WORKING
                     <Person key={person.name} person={person}/> // <--- NOT WORKING
                )

            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

**components/Person.js**

```
import React from "react";
const Person = ({person}) => {
        return (
            <p key={person.name}>{person.name} {person.number}</p>
        )
    }

export default Person
```

**Error Message**

```
InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character
./src/index.js
src/index.js:6

  3 | import './index.css';
  4 | import App from './App';
  5 | 
> 6 | ReactDOM.render(
  7 |   <React.StrictMode>
  8 |     <App />
  9 |   </React.StrictMode>,

__webpack_require__
/home/thbruhn/Programmes/part2/webpack/bootstrap:784

  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;

fn
/home/thbruhn/Programmes/part2/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:246:18
__webpack_require__
/home/thbruhn/Programmes/part2/webpack/bootstrap:784

  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;

checkDeferredModules
/home/thbruhn/Programmes/part2/webpack/bootstrap:45

  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 

webpackJsonpCallback
/home/thbruhn/Programmes/part2/webpack/bootstrap:32

  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;

(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:63
```

Comment: I'm not seeing that issue when I run the code you have posted. Any thoughts on what's missing to get the issue reproducible?

Comment: Yes a really demotivating one. The the file with the Person component did not have a .js ending. There is a reason why I am not a programmer 

Comment: Glad you figured it out! A lot of programming is learning from your mistakes and trying not to do them again.